# path variable: why it was still there when echo %path%, after the deletion?

Tags: path, php-5.6

I was trying to upgrade my php version from 5.3 to 5.6. I removed the old php 5.3 entry and added the new php 5.6 entry in the path variable. But why when I echo %path% in the command line, it always gave me both entries?

Answer (score 0):

okay, the problem was solved: I closed the command line, and reopened a new one... echo %path% worked as expected.